# What is the Overview Ruler Minimap of Pydev in Eclipse highlighting?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I understand that the Minimap is highlighting the occurrences of e.g. a variable in my script if I click at it (yellow). But there are also those dark grey bars, which at first I thought are imports, global variables or functions. But at least in two of my scripts, not all of my functions have those bars and some random lines do (e.g. empty lines). So what are those grey bars supposed to highlight?

I also thought it could be a bug, because I collapse some of my functions. Also, when I deleted one empty line with a dark bar, it disappeared (the bar) and another one appeared for a different line.

Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and Pydev 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is definitively a bug caused by collapsing the code, which I will report.
Here is an example with an uncollapsed and collapsed function:
[image: uncollapsed code]

[image: collapsed code]

Answer (score 0):

That may be a setting on Eclipse side and not specific of PyDev.

Open Eclipse preferences and go to: **General** > **Editors** > **Text Editors** > **Annotations**.

There you see a list of possible annotations. Each one have an icon that will show up on the *Vertical ruler* (left side) and/or a *Color* on the *Overview ruler* (right side).

Here is a snapshot from my current settings (which I think corresponds to the default).

[image: Eclipse Annotations]

You may check each item in this list and look for the one that matches the dark grey color you are seeing.